# How to update the origination_urls when creating a new Trunk using twilio API

Tags: twilio-api

Thanks to this tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/api/trunks#action-create I am able to CRUD create, read, update and delete trunks on my Twilio account.

To create a new trunk I do it like so:

```
curl -XPOST https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks \
  -d "FriendlyName=MyTrunk" \
  -u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```

and this is the response I get when creating a new trunk:

```
    {
        "trunks": [
        {
            "sid": "TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932",
            "account_sid": "ACxxx",
             ....
             ....
            "date_updated": "2015-09-02T23:23:11Z",
            "url": "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932",
            "links": {
                "origination_urls": "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/OriginationUrls",
                "credential_lists": "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/CredentialLists",
                "ip_access_control_lists": "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/IpAccessControlLists",
                 "phone_numbers": "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/PhoneNumbers"
            }
        }],
        "meta": {
            "page": 0,
             "page_size": 50,
              ... more
        }
    }
```

What I am interested from the response is:

```
    "links": {
                "origination_urls": "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/OriginationUrls",
```

Now if I perform a get command on that link like:

```
curl -G "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/OriginationUrls" -u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```

I get back this:

```
{
    "meta": 
    {
       "page": 0, 
       "page_size": 50, 
        "first_page_url":
        .... 
    }, 
    "origination_urls": []
}
```

**Now my goal is to update the `origination_urls`**. So using the same approach I used to update a trunk I have tried:

```
curl -XPOST https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/OriginationUrls \
  -d "origination_urls=sip:200@somedomain.com" \
  -u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```

But that fails. I  have also tried:

```
curl -XPOST https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfa1e5a85f63bfc475c2c753c0f289932/OriginationUrls \
  -d "origination_urls=['someUrl']" \
  -u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```

and that fails too. **How can I update the origination_urls?**

Answer (score 0):

I was missing to add Priority, FriendlyName, SipUrl, Weight and Enabled on my post request. I finally got it to work by doing:

```
curl -XPOST "https://trunking.twilio.com/v1/Trunks/TKfae10...../OriginationUrls"   -d "Priority=10" -d "FriendlyName=Org1"  -d "Enabled=true" -d "SipUrl=sip:test@domain.com" -d "Weight=10" -u '{twilio account sid}:{twilio auth token}'
```